# Separating input string and call the required function using case statement

Tags: haskell

How can I separate the input string into two parts, first of which is a function and the second is the parameter. I want to call the function using the case statement in Haskell.

For example: I have a function `sum` which calculates the sum of the elements in a list and if a user writes `sum 9` it must calculate the sum of the first 9 elements of the list.

Comment: better to include your tried code?

Comment: Are you trying to interpret strings of Haskell snippets in Haskell at runtime?  It isn't clear from the question.  Does the input need to be lazy (ie- can the user type in line after line and get answers back in realtime).  I think we need more info.

Comment: there is a list generated through a recursive function and then the user just tells the function he wants to perform with a space followed by the parameter.the output will be given as soon as he hits enter.If the command entered by the user does not match any of the given functions it will throw an error

Answer (score 1):

First `import Data.List`, which has all the list manipulation functions.
Then to split at the first space, use `span`. Then drop the first element of the second half of the list, since that will be the space. The code is then:

```
import Data.List
f :: String -> (String, String)
f s = (func, tail args)
  where (func, args) = span (/=' ') s
```

EDIT: Oh yeah, for the second part of your question. You're not adding functions to your list of callable functions at runtime right? So just make another function and pattern match on the first argument string, and call the appropriate function. This only works if your always returning an int though. I'm not sure how to make this work on generic return types Example:

```
eval :: (String, String) -> Int
eval ("sum", args) = sum (take (read . head $ args') (read . concat . tail $ words))
  where args' = words args
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) to split the string at the spaces.
You can then use a case expression and match on the function name and parameters.
If you only want to print the result you can work directly in the `IO` monad,
which allows you to work with functions of different return types:

```
evaluationLoop :: IO ()
evaluationLoop = do
  input <- getLine
  case words input of
    "add"    : xs -> (print $ sum $ map read xs) >> evaluationLoop
    "concat" : xs -> (putStrLn $ concat xs)      >> evaluationLoop        
    "exit"   : [] -> return ()
```

You can then use it like this:

```
ghci> evaluationLoop 
add 1 2 3 4 5
15
add -4 14
10
concat a hello 
ahello
concat hi 
hi
exit
ghci>
```